# ElasticSearch massive purge of deleted documents reasons? (AWS ES service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Is there any info when and why ES may trigger automatically purge of documents marked for deletion?

Where can be found logs with possible info about trigger?

The service in question is actually AWS ES, but I do not think it is related to the topic.. may be I'm wrong?

The version in question is `ElasticSearch 5.1`

Answer (score 0):

when the merge happens, the marked document will be purged. 
there are some merge policies that indicate when the merge process triggered. for example, the number of segment's files is more than 300 or the marked document is more than 15% of a segment. 
there is some information here for elasticsearch 1.4: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-merge.html

It seems that the developers don't want to clarify the policies anymore.

this is an example of merge policy settings:

```
  "merge": {
    "scheduler": {
      "max_thread_count": "1",
      "auto_throttle": "true",
      "max_merge_count": "6"
    },
    "policy": {
      "reclaim_deletes_weight": "2.0",
      "floor_segment": "2mb",
      "max_merge_at_once_explicit": "30",
      "max_merge_at_once": "10",
      "max_merged_segment": "5gb",
      "expunge_deletes_allowed": "10.0",
      "segments_per_tier": "10.0",
      "deletes_pct_allowed": "33.0"
    }
```

for logging a merge process I think you should change logs level to INFO or DEBUG. (log4j settings)